# Is there an OrderedDict comprehension?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I don't know if there is such a thing - but I'm trying to do an ordered dict comprehension.  However it doesn't seem to work?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
t_data = OrderedDict()
rows = tables[1].find_all('tr')
t_data = {row.th.text: row.td.text for row in rows if row.td }
```

It's left as a normal dict comprehension for now (I've also left out the usual requests to soup boilerplate).
Any ideas?

Comment: No, there's no such thing as an OrderedDict comprehension, you just get a regular dictionary. The fact that you've previously assigned an OrderedDict to that name is irrelevant.

Comment: There is no such thing as creating an empty  dict and then adding elements to it with a dict comp with an OrderedDict or any dict, once you rebind the name `t_data` it no longer points to your OrderedDict

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can't directly do a comprehension with an `OrderedDict`. You can, however, use a generator in the constructor for `OrderedDict`.

Try this on for size:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
rows = tables[1].find_all('tr')
t_data = OrderedDict((row.th.text, row.td.text) for row in rows if row.td)
```